# How to query star (*) character in a field in where clause for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, where-clause

I want to query a table with field that contains star (*) character but I could't find a valuable answer. I tried something below

```
WHERE fieldName regexp '\*'
```

There are solutions like using 'like' keyword but I wanna know a way that uses 'regexp' keyword.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I found why it didn't work. I have a bunch of criteria. Some of them are against others. That's why it didn't work. Thank you for your comments though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash one more time since a single backslash inside double or single quotes would be considered as an escape sequence.

```
WHERE fieldName regexp '\\*'
```

**OR**

Use character class.

```
WHERE fieldName regexp '[*]'
```